# Google Play Store Test for testing without invites

Tags: android, google-play, release, publish, google-play-console

Is it possible to release a "closed beta app" for several users without having to invite them? 
I just want to send a link, which can be distributed further. 
The app should automatically update, but I don't want to send the apk to the testers every time I update

Comment: What you describe would be an Open Beta. Note that according to Google's documentation it's no longer possible to set up Closed Beta tests (existing ones can still be used).

Comment: but wouldn't the app be listed in the app store then as well?

Comment: Yes, an Open Beta would be listed on Google Play, at least for the testers (not sure if non-testers can see the listing). A Closed Alpha should still be possible to create, but that would either require you to have the email addresses of the testers, or require the testers to join a Google Group which you add as the test group.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in between "Open beta" where anyone can see the store listing and a closed testing track, where only invited people can see it.